# Trying to get status code from URL - getting java.net.ProtocolException: Unsupported protocol: https

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible for a site having URL starting with “http://” using HTTPS protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161386/is-it-possible-for-a-site-having-url-starting-with-http-using-https-protoco)

Trying to get status code from URL - getting java.net.ProtocolException: Unsupported protocol: https for a particular URL whose http status code i want to retrieve.

```
String link = "http://abc.def.ghi.jkl";
URL thisURL;
HttpURLConnection conn = null;

thisURL = new URL(link);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) thisURL.openConnection();
System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());   // getting exception in this line
System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
```

This is the exception stack trace :

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unsupported protocol: https'
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:342)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:238)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:172)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:643)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:422)
    at           weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:36)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:947)
    at com.cingular.cscape.da.struts.action.thisAction.executeAction(thisAction.java:56)
    at com.cingular.cscape.da.struts.action.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:300)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at org.extremecomponents.table.filter.AbstractExportFilter.doFilter(AbstractExportFilter.java:53)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a WebLogic specific problem from the stack trace...

Comment: Can you please let me know why does it look like a WebLogic specific problem because it is not working for a specific url only? But for other URLs it is working.

Comment: Because of the first lines in the stack trace. By any chance, for the non working URL, is there a redirect to an HTTPS URL instead? And what happens if you try your code with an HTTPS URL directly?

Comment: If i try my code with the HTTPS URL directly it gives me following error:<Jan 4, 2013 9:54:45 PM IST> <Warning> <Security> <BEA-090477> <Certificate chain received from abc.def.ghi.jkl - 144.155.215.36 was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure.> 
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090477]Certificate chain received from abc.def.ghi.jkl - 144.155.215.36 was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure.